# Create link in Atom markdown editor

Tags: markdown, atom-editor

I'm trying to create a link in markdown file in Atom. I have the text "VLC" that I want to link to the text "Install VLC" further down in the file.

I've tried this:

`[VLC](#vlc)` for the text clickable text "VLC"

and this:

`<a name="vlc"></a>Install VLC` for the "Install VLC" anchor

In the markdown preview window (I'm using the `markdown-preview` package) "VLC" comes up marked in blue and the pointer changes to a hand with finger but nothing happens when I click on the text.

Any suggestions what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You can't follow github markdown links in the Atom preview window.

Comment: @MattSchuchard thank Matt. Can I make the link any other way that will work on Atom?

Comment: Not that I know of. Actually, I just googled and found that external links should work, but relative links within a file or to other files do not. The former is what you are trying to do and seems like it should be feasible. 
There seems to to be an open issue for it also.

Answer (score 1):

for anyone interested
I've found out [markdown-preview-enhanced](https://atom.io/packages/markdown-preview-enhanced) do the thing, plus some more nice features like "go to the top" or "auto-menu" (constructed from headers)